What exactly God heard in Jesus' prayer in Heb 5:7

Who in the days of his flesh, when he had offered up prayers and
supplications with strong crying and tears unto him that was able to
save him from death, and was heard in that he feared. (KJV),(YLT),(WEB).*

According to the verse, can we say that God did not hear Jesus' prayer itself (asking him not to die) but heard something else in which Jesus feared God?
I guess that could be supported by the meaning of the word fear εὐλάβεια which also means reverence toward God, godly fear, piety  (Strong's G2124 - eulabeia)
I mean Jesus prayed to God to not die but in fact this prayer hold something in it that reflected Jesus' reverence to God (and God heard this reverence).
That would mean that Jesus actually was trying hard to not be a high priest. He humbled himself and did not glorify himself to take that position and that humbleness is what God heard in Jesus' prayer.

First, let me quote the very literal version from the BLB for Heb 5:7 -

He in the days of His flesh, having offered up both prayers and
supplications with loud crying and tears to the One being able to save
Him from death, and having been heard because of reverent submission,

This text is essentially saying several things:

Jesus felt the need for prayers and petitions to the Father during His earthly ministry
the Father was capable of saving Jesus from death on the cross
Jesus' prayers were very earnest as evidenced by "loud cries and tears"
the Father "heard" Jesus' prayers because of His "reverent submission"

The "reverent submission" translates the Greek word εὐλάβεια (eulabeia) which only occurs in Heb 5:7 and 12:28. According to BDAG it means:

reverent awe in the presence of God, awe, fear of God

The situation is best illustrated with the facts of what happened in the Garden as recorded by Matthew -

Matt 26:29 - Going a little farther, He fell facedown and prayed, “My
Father, if it is possible, let this cup pass from Me. Yet not as I
will, but as You will.”

This perfectly illustrates two things about Jesus' ministry on earth:

Jesus' complete submission to the Father's will despite His own human reluctance
that reverent piety involves reverent submission when we compare the two above quoted texts.


The KJV, YLP and WEB versions are different than the others in that they don't say "because of his reverent submission". So the question is about what is in the KJV (or YLP and WEB). So according to KJV do you still have the same stance?

@GamalThomas - the KJV is a bit misleading in this case - the word "feared" means something different from that in 1611.

What do you mean by 1611 plz?

@GamalThomas - 1611 is when the KJV was translated.  That is why it uses dated Elizabethan language.

The same words are in The World English Bible (WEB) version which is an English translation of the Bible freely shared online. The translation work began in 1994 and was deemed complete in 2020.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_English_Bible#:~:text=The%20World%20English%20Bible%20(WEB,was%20deemed%20complete%20in%202020.

In Hebrews 5:7, it says, "During the days of Jesus' life on earth, he offered up prayers and petitions with fervent cries and tears to the one who could save him from death, and he was heard because of his reverent submission." This verse provides a profound insight into the nature of Jesus' prayers and how God responded to them.
When we consider what God "heard" in Jesus' prayer, it's essential to look at the context. Jesus was known for his deep and earnest prayers, often filled with emotion, especially during times of distress. In this passage, the emphasis is on the intensity of his prayers—described as fervent cries and tears—which reflects his deep anguish and earnestness in seeking God's will.
The phrase "he was heard because of his reverent submission" indicates that God's response was not necessarily about granting Jesus' request to be saved from death, but rather affirming his submission to God's will. Jesus' prayers were an expression of his humanity and the struggle he faced, particularly leading up to his crucifixion. In these moments, he was seeking strength to fulfill his mission and obedience to the Father's plan.
Ultimately, what God heard was a heartfelt expression of Jesus' willingness to submit to God's will, even in the face of suffering. This reflects a profound relationship between Jesus and the Father, characterized by trust, obedience, and a shared purpose. Jesus' example teaches us about the importance of earnest prayer, submission to God's will, and the assurance that God listens, even in our most challenging moments.

You agree that God's response was not necessarily about granting Jesus' request to be saved from death, but I do not agree that it was about Jesus' willingness to submit to God's wil. The chapter or the whole Epistle does not mention that. It is simply an explanation to how Jesus did not seek to gloryfiy himself to be a high priest. By asking to not die equals asking to not be a high priest equals not seeking to  that position. It was that humbleness that God heard and based on that God saw that Jesus did the requirements to be a high priest so God called him to that position. Agree?
